# NSUserDefaultsController: "Attempt to set a non-property-list object ... as an NSUserDefaults/CFPreferences value for key ..."

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsuserdefaults, codable, nscoding

I'm trying to use `NSUserDefaultsController` to implement a Preferences window in my Swift macOS app.

One of the settings that I need to persist is an array of presets, as defined by the following class:

```
class Preset: NSObject {
    var name = "abc"
    var value = 123

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }
}
```

Therefore, I need to persist a variable of type `[Presets]`. The visual representation in my Preferences window is an `NSTableView`, bound to an `NSArrayController`.

I followed [this](http://daemonconstruction.blogspot.com/2011/11/simple-nstableview-application-with.html) tutorial to set up my bindings. When running the app and trying to add a new preset (by clicking the `+` button), I get the following errors:

```
[User Defaults] Attempt to set a non-property-list object (...) as an NSUserDefaults/CFPreferences value for key presets
[General] Attempt to insert non-property list object (...) for key presets
```

I've tried implementing the `Codable` and `NSCoding` protocols, but the error persists.

From searching similar questions in Stack Overflow (such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41355427/attempt-to-insert-non-property-list-object-when-trying-to-save-a-custom-object-i/41355671) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19720611/attempt-to-set-a-non-property-list-object-as-an-nsuserdefaults)), it appears the solution would involve `NSKeyedArchiver` and `NSKeyedUnarchiver`. That appears simple enough to do if you're manually triggering loads and saves. Unfortunately I don't see how to use these classes along with `NSUserDefaultsController`.

Comment: If you want to use `NSUserDefaultsController` and Cocoa Bindings you have to implement a `ValueTransformer` to serialize the custom objects. I recommend to use `Codable`, then a simple struct is sufficient.

Comment: @vadian I am a Cocoa/Swift newbie. Could you elaborate a bit? Do you mean I need to implement a class that inherits from `ValueTransformer` and implements the `Codable` protocol? Perhaps you could make this into an answer -- it looks like this will solve my problem, and I can accept it.

Comment: No, the data model is a normal struct or class adopting `Codable`. Assuming there is a array `@objc dynamic var presets = [Preset]()` you have to implement a subclass of `ValueTransformer` to decode and encode the array from and to `Data`. Then you can bind `presets` to the `NSUserDefaultsController` applying the value transformer.

Comment: OK, I know I'm supposed to show a little effort here, but I'm a complete newbie and I'm lost. So I need to make a class with a single property, `@objc dynamic var presets = [Preset]()`? If you could make a step-by-step answer I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by subclassing `NSArrayController` as follows (see comment by Hamish to [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54392379/convert-swift-encodable-class-typed-as-any-to-dictionary), which was the last missing piece of the puzzle to make this generic):

```
extension Encodable {
    fileprivate func encode(to container: inout SingleValueEncodingContainer) throws {
        try container.encode(self)
    }
}

struct AnyEncodable: Encodable {
    var value: Encodable
    init(_ value: Encodable) {
        self.value = value
    }
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        try value.encode(to: &container)
    }
}

class NSEncodableArrayController: NSArrayController {
    override func addObject(_ object: Any) {
        let data = try! PropertyListEncoder().encode(AnyEncodable(object as! Encodable))
        let any = try! PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: data, options: [], format: nil)

        super.addObject(any)
    }
}
```