# Not sure how to use unarchivedDictionary to resolve a NSInvalidArgumentException crash using userDefaults within Swift

Tags: swift, nsdictionary

I'm hitting the issue documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41355427/attempt-to-insert-non-property-list-object-when-trying-to-save-a-custom-object-i) and I'm trying to utilize `NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedDictionary`, but I'm not sure what `KeysofClasses` or `objectsOfClasses` is wanting.

The structure of my dictionary is: `[Int: [String: String]]`

A bit of my code:

```
let encodedData = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: widgetDictionary, requiringSecureCoding: false)

let outData = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "flaggedWidgetDictKey")
let decodedData = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedDictionary(keysOfClasses:  [Int: [String: String]], objectsOfClasses: [Int: [String: String]], from: outData!))
```

The error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attempt to insert non-property
> list object for key jobCategory'

Comment: Seeing the error, it seems that `archivedData` is creating the issue... What is `widgetDictionary`?

Comment: the `archivedData` is my attempt to resolve the crash. Before that I was doing `userDefaults?.set(widgetDictionary, forKey: "flaggedWidgetDictKey")` The `widgetDictionary` is `[0: ["Foo" : "Data"]]`

Comment: Concerning the previous error, I'm wondering if that's because the key of the diictionary can't be `Int` to be PropertyList Compliant, (as it's the same for JSON), to verify...

Comment: That would be interesting if `Int` could not be a key since Apple's documentation says it can https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary or maybe I'm reading it wrong.

Comment: I meant in a "plist". For instance, you can put a lot of things as key in a dictionary, but in JSON, only strings keys are allowed. So it could have been the same for Plist compliance. But it seems it doesn't matteer. Now, I'd avoiid `NSArchiver`, especially for just a Dictionary. I'd use Plist Encoder (since it's not JSON compatible).